# Entity Framework: Two propertes with same class issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

As I am not so experienced with EntityFramwork, I am facing problems. I need to track which user created the Transaction and which user modified that transaction. This means I have **two properties having the same class.**

Here is the list of the properties in Transaction Class:

```
public virtual System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
public virtual System.DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
public virtual string Description { get; set; }

public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

Whenever the `context.SaveChanges()` is called i get the following exception:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Model.Entities.User' and 'Model.Entities.User'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

Comment: So.. Show your fluent API/Annotation mapping?

Comment: Show as your mapping, it is possible that both classes are pointing to each other thus it cannot determine the principal end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the OnModelCreating method in your dbcontext class and add the following code

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction)()
 .HasOptional<User>(x => x.CreatedBy);


 modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction)()
 .HasOptional<User>(x => x.ModifiedBy);
```

Of course HasOptional can also be hasrequired.